# Are there any differences between the future in the past when using "would" & reported speech when changing "will" to "would"?

Tags: indirect-speech, future-in-past

[This site](http://www.vivquarry.com/wkshts/narrative.html) said:

> The future in the past is used to look into the future from a point of
>   time in the past. However, **this "future" event still occurred at a
>   time before the present time.**

[image]

> E.g. *I woke up (1) at 8am yesterday. I was meeting my boss (2) at ten
>   o'clock that morning, so I wouldn't be able to have lunch (3) with
>   Susan. I wasn't going to get home (4) again until late that night.*

But, see this example in reported speech:

Let say today is Monday & at 1 PM, A says "*I will have lunch with Susan tomorrow*".

Ok, at 2 PM, B says "*She said she would have lunch with Susan tomorrow*".

My question is that:

So, the law of Reported speech does not adhere the law of the future in the past, right?

Because the law of the future in the past said **the-future-in-the past event still occurred at a time before the present time.** but the action "**would have lunch with Susan tomorrow**" will not happen before now.

However, let say, at 3pm on Wednesday, B says "*She said she would have lunch with Susan yesterday*", then it adheres to the law of the future in the past because that action occurred before now.

So, Are there any differences between the future in the past when using "**would**" & reported speech when changing "**will**" to "**would**"?

Comment: @Jim, but why "She said she would have lunch with Susan tomorrow" does not adhere to the law of the future in the past

Comment: Monday at 2pm B might have said instead “She said she will have lunch with Susan tomorrow.” it doesn’t matter here.

Comment: It’s not future in the past, it’s future in the future.  Tuesday hasn’t happened yet on Monday at 2pm.

Comment: @Jim, This site (http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html) say "He promised he would send a postcard from Egypt." is a future-in-the-past sentence. So, if that sentence stands alone, then we don't know if it is a reported speech form or future-in-the-past right?